# How to hide an API key on client side?

Tags: javascript, api

I know I'm not supposed to put API keys in the client side, but I can't think of a way around it. I am trying to integrate Google Pay on a website, and the payment processor is Paysafe. The Google Pay code is on the client side, and it requires the Paysafe API key (which needs to be kept secret) in the code.

Is it safe to put the API key in a json file on the server, and call that file for the key when it's required? Or is it still going to be exposed to the client?

Comment: All network requests (and corresponding responses) are visible to the user, therefore hiding the secret behind an API will not prevent anything if it's actually being returned to the user.

Comment: You can't hide anything on client side. Make request to server and then using back-end create API request to Paysafe

Answer (score 0):

Try using a proxy server, where you can keep the API credentials.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a "Single-Use Token API key" on the client, not the "Server-to-Server API key".

Comment: Ohh OK, makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @CameronChin You can "accept" the answer if you're satisfied with it, or update your question if you need more details.